# NSTableView with NSArrayController Core Data Drag and Drop

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I'm trying to get drag & drop working between two `NSTableViews` that use `NSArrayControllers` that in turn use Core Data. I found a solution that explains drag and drop with basic arrays and my basic drag & drop functionality between the two tables works but I need to figure out how to move the data from the source AC to the target AC, in particular with respect on Core Data.

My `NSTableViewDataSource` methods for the target table are like this:

```
// MARK: - NSTableViewDataSource
extension TargetTableViewController : NSTableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(aTableView:NSTableView, validateDrop info:NSDraggingInfo, proposedRow row:Int, proposedDropOperation operation:NSTableViewDropOperation) -> NSDragOperation
    {
        if (operation == .Above)
        {
            return .Move;
        }
        return .Every;
    }


    func tableView(tableView:NSTableView, acceptDrop info:NSDraggingInfo, row:Int, dropOperation:NSTableViewDropOperation) -> Bool
    {
        var data:NSData = info.draggingPasteboard().dataForType(NSStringPboardType)!;
        var rowIndexes:NSIndexSet = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! NSIndexSet;

        if ((info.draggingSource() as? NSTableView == sourceTableView) && (tableView == targetTableView))
        {
            //var value:String = sourceDataArray[rowIndexes.firstIndex];
            //sourceDataArray.removeAtIndex(rowIndexes.firstIndex);
            //targetDataArray.append(value);

            sourceTableView!.reloadData();
            targetTableView.reloadData();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously I need to get the selected data from the source AC and move it into the target AC but I don't know how to do that for Core Data managed objects. Does anyone have a solution for this?